# JSON Schema attribute definition: Unsupported field schema for field... : Unknown field type undefined

Tags: reactjs, json, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

I'm trying to build a form based on a [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/) and using the [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form) component for ReactJS.

I want to use this to display a form that users can fill with various settings (CSS/HTML selectors, etc) that will be used to parse playlist tracks datas on remote webpages.

I have a *selector* definition in my JSON schema, like this :

```
"definitions":{
  "selector":{
    "$id":        "#/definitions/selector",
    "type":       "object",
    "title":      "CSS or HTML selector used to extract datas.",
    "required":   [],
    "properties":{
      "path":{
        "type":     "string",
        "title":    "Selector path",
        "default":  "",
        "examples": ["#playlist .track .title"]
      },
      "multiple":{
        "type":     "boolean",
        "title":    "Should we extract multiple values?",
        "default":  false,
        "readOnly": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My JSON schema for parsing tracks look then like this:

```
    "track":{
      "$id": "#/properties/selectors/properties/track",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Track selectors",
      "required": [
        "title"
      ],
      "properties":{
        "artist":{
          "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
          "title": "Track artist"
        },
        "title":{
          "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
          "title": "Track title"
        },
        "album":{
          "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
          "title": "Track album"
        },
        "image":{
          "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
          "title": "Track image"
        },
        "duration":{
          "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
          "title": "Track duration"
        },
        "location":{
          "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
          "title": "Track locations",
          "properties":{
            "multiple":{
              "default": true
            }
          }
        },
        "link":{
          "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
          "title": "Track links",
          "properties":{
            "multiple":{
              "default": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

As you see, the *selector definition* is used for the *artist, title, album, image, duration, location* and *link* attributes.

the *multiple* attribute of the *selector definition* is used to know if the parser should extract **a single or multiple values**.

Its *readonly* attribute is set to `true` because the user cannot choose this: I know a track has only ONE artist, title, album, image and duration, **but** might have several location (files) and links attached to.

```
"location":{
  "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
  "title": "Track locations",
  "properties":{
    "multiple":{
      "default": true
    }
  }
},
"link":{
  "$ref": "#/definitions/selector",
  "title": "Track links",
  "properties":{
    "multiple":{
      "default": true
    }
  }
}
```

This is where I have a problem:
When displaying those two fields, react-jsonschema-form renders those errors:

```
Track locations
multiple
Unsupported field schema for field root_selectors_track_location_multiple: Unknown field type undefined.

{
  "default": true
}
Track links
multiple
Unsupported field schema for field root_selectors_track_link_multiple: Unknown field type undefined.

{
  "default": true
}
```

I don't know if this occurs because my JSON schema is not well defined (can I "override" the properties of a definition like this ?) or if this is a bug of react-jsonschema-form.

Can someone help ?

Thanks for your long read!

Answer (score 2):

From what I can read in the documentation, the react JSON schema forms library supports draft-07 of the JSON schema specification. In this case, any schema keyword beside `$ref` at this sub-schema level is simply ignored.

From https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#ref

> In Draft 4-7, $ref behaves a little differently. When an object
> contains a $ref property, the object is considered a reference, not a
> schema. Therefore, any other properties you put in that object will
> not be treated as JSON Schema keywords and will be ignored by the
> validator. $ref can only be used where a schema is expected.

You will need to change your schema to reflect this. An option could be to surround your extension with `allOf`:

```
"location": {
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/selector" },
    {
      "title": "Track locations",
      "properties": {
        "multiple":{
          "default": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer.  So there is no way to "extend" a definition ?

Comment: @gordie I added a possible way to do it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It seems that it does not work : setting `"default":true` for the _multiple_ attribute WITHIN the definition makes react-jsonschema-form display a checked box; while doing it your way with allOf renders an unchecked box.

Comment: Maybe it works when you change the order and put the $ref as the second item in the allOf? This is more related to the forms library and not the schema/validator.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens.  I found [this link](https://groups.google.com/g/json-schema/c/hjemODGbW0g/m/a4Pg0GMILC8J) and made an attempt like this : 
`"location":{"title": "Track locations","allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/selector" }],"properties": {"multiple":{"default": true}}}`
And it works ! Except that the _multiple_ field appears on the top of the form while it shoud appear at the bottom.  But it seems it works to extend it like that.

Comment: Got the same problem.  Your code seems valid regarding the JSON Schema 2020-12 specs; which should be supported within AJV 8 validator.  I don't understand why this does not work.